# Why do I type listobject.autofilter in one case and listobject.range.autofilter in another case?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Dim lo as listobject

'Show all data
lo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

'Set new filter
lo.Range.AutoFilter Field:="X", Criteria1:=vFilterCriteria, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Both rows above work. The second row does not work if I remove `.Range`. But the above line does not require me to write `.Range`. Why are the cases different?

Comment: Hint: [`ListObject` members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839458(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: Thank you. I see that the autofilter property of listobject is read-only. How do you learn all these details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just the way the object model works.

Before tables (ListObjects) were introduced, you could only have one autofilter applied to a sheet. You applied it using the Autofilter method of the Range object - presumably for consistency with how you apply an advanced filter, and possibly with the old XLM FILTER command.

The Autofilter property of the Worksheet returned the Autofilter object, which allowed you to clear the filter or *test* properties of the filter, but not change them. (the worksheet also had a ShowAllData method since you can use advanced filters as well as autofilters)

I can only surmise that when Tables (listobjects) were introduced, it was easier simply to implement the same Autofilter object as a property of the table.

Comment: ++ well explained! I think you're right about the introduction of `ListObjects` and the idea **NOT** to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer! How does a person learn all these details?

Comment: I'd say mostly experience. But reading docs and learning object models (as they slightly change over the years) can give you a full and deep understanding of why things are the way they are.

Answer (score 0):

there are other oddities associated with this history -- if your active cell or selection is within a ListObject Table which has filters active, activeworksheet.filtermode = true; if outside the table, then activeworksheet.filtermode = false.  This in/out disparity does not happen with ordinary filtered Ranges