# Delete multiple, not adjacent rows at once

Tags: excel, vba, listobject

I have a table in a sheet (see Image).

[image]

I want to delete the entire row for the selection at once. I tried the following:

```
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
```

but unfortunately it returns an Error "Runtime Error "1004", Delete Method of Range class failed"

Is there any solution other than Loops or unlist the table?

Comment: remove the `Entirerow` you're dealing with a listobject it behaves differently from a range.

Comment: so How can I do it for a listobject ?

Comment: With `Selection.Delete`

Comment: Or loop through the rows of the selection: `For Each myRow In Selection // Rows(myRow).EntireRow.Delete // Next myRow`

Comment: Or apply a filter and delete visible.

Comment: Just know that applying a filter for a listobject is also different than normally. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867979/why-do-i-type-listobject-autofilter-in-one-case-and-listobject-range-autofilter)